# Does a std::vector created with managed_shared_object require synchronization?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess

I succesfully compiled the [Creating vectors in shared memory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) example from Boost. I'm uncertain if insertions into the constructed vector from multiple processes are safe (automatically synchronized intern). The documentation talks about [Synchronization guarantees](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features.synchronization) but this only refers the creation/search/destruction of the shared memory.

Do you know if I have to synchronize vector accesses (insertions, deletion, iteration) manually with e.g. `scoped_lock<named_mutex>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you created is a `std::vector`, so boost can't have added any synchronization to the standard library class. Just like any other `std::vector`, you'll have to synchronize it manually.

Comment: It's the first time I'm dealing with shared memory and was not sure if there's something going on behind the scenes (particularly the `ShmemAllocator` with which the vector was generated). Thank you for clarification.

Comment: There is indeed - the allocator itself is synchronized, so that different processes can allocate from the same segment. It just doesn't help you out with the container-level semantics above that.